# Problems with AppDomain and used DLL after unload

Tags: c#, plugins, service, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I've a problem that a DLL loaded to my new Appdomain is also loaded to the main appdomain!

I have a class "Servicebase" which inherits from MarshalByRefObject.

Now I have different child classes which inherit from this base class.

These child classes should be instantiated in their own app domain.

This I do with this code:

```
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(dllFile);
        setup.ApplicationName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dllFile);
        setup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost;
        setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
        setup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;

        hostAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(setup.ApplicationName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);
```

this works...

now I create my instance with this code:

```
    host = hostAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(dllFile, className.Split(',')[0]);
```

when I now check with "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" my instance assembly is not loaded into my main assembly.

But after executing this:

```
            var inst = (ServiceBase)host.Unwrap();
```

my current assembly has also loaded the dll.

Can anybody tell my why? And what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is ServiceBase on the same assembly with the derived classes?

If it is then you should split them into two different assemblies. One with the contract (the base class) and the other with the derived classes. Then you will not reference the derived classes assembly from your main project. Only the contract assembly should be referenced by the main project and only that will be loaded in the main AppDomain.